# class io.vertx.core.buffer.impl.VertxUnsafeHeapByteBuf cannot access its superclass io.netty.buffer.UnpooledUnsafeHeapByteBuf

Tags: java, netty, vert.x

Using vertx-mqtt 4.0.2 with jdk 8. I'm getting the following exception when trying to publish message using the mqtt client:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class io.vertx.core.buffer.impl.VertxUnsafeHeapByteBuf cannot access its superclass io.netty.buffer.UnpooledUnsafeHeapByteBuf
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
```

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65903988/java-lang-illegalaccesserror-when-using-vertx-web-client-version-4-0-0 , seems to be duplicate

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.lang.IllegalAccessError when using vertx web client version 4.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65903988/java-lang-illegalaccesserror-when-using-vertx-web-client-version-4-0-0)